# please explain this c code snippet mult(x,y)x*y?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define mult(x,y)x*y  /* what does this mean ?? */

int main() 
{
  int a,b,answer;
  b=5;
  a=5;

  answer=mult(a+b,a+b);
  printf("%d",answer);

  return 0;
}
```

I'm using compiler gcc-4.9.2

Comment: It's simply a macro with two arguments. Both get substituted by `a+b`. A demonstration of what happens if you don't use parantheses around macro arguments.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly you want to know what `#define mult(x,y) x*y` does.

This a definition of a macro, during the compilation the compiler will replace, everywhere in the code, `mult(x, y)` by `x*y`.

In your code:
`answer=mult(a+b,a+b);`

Will be replaced by: `answer=a+b*a+b;`

Whence the answer will be `35`.

A correct way to use macros and to ensure they work properly is to include parentheses where they might be needed.

Therefore your define would be: `#define mult(x, y) ((x)*(y))` to ensure the result is what you would expect `100`

Comment: I would suggest even more parentheses: `((x)*(y))`

Comment: You are correct, since you might want to use it in another function

Comment: Hi @SeetharamAllamraju if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.